# Unable to install Rcpp package when loading forecast

Tags: r, rcpp, install.packages

When I try to load the forecast package it trows me the error that there is not Rcpp package which it depends on

by trying to install Rcpp package manually i get the following error

> install.packages("Rcpp")

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/~~~’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary  source needs_compilation
Rcpp 0.12.10 0.12.11              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.10.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.10.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.10.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘Rcpp’ failed
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a likely duplicate.  You misunderstand the meaning of *There is a binary version available but the source version is later.*.

Install from source, use a different mirror, or just wait.

The 0.12.11 binary is [clearly there in Vienna and at the 0-cloud mirrors](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html).